# No se visualiza imagen al compartir en facebook

Tags: html, angularjs, facebook

Hola estoy usando la librería de Angular Socialshare y al momento de compartir en Facebook no se visualiza la imagen, simplemente se ve el texto del contenido de la página este es el código...

```
<a href="" 
  socialshare 
  socialshare-provider="facebook"  
  socialshare-type="feed"
  socialshare-via="1740491275981023" 
  socialshare-media="http://ip:3001/images/logo.png"
  socialshare-text="Caso Relevante"
  socialshare-caption="PC"
  socialshare-url="http://ip:3001/operador"
  socialshare-quote="720kb Angular-Social-Share"
  socialshare-hashtags="#Saludos"
  socialshare-popup-height="300" 
  socialshare-popup-width="400"                            
  socialshare-trigger="click">
  <img src="../../images/facebooklogo.png" style="max-width: 1.5%" >
</a>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si me falta alguna etiqueta o configuración para que se vea una imagen precargada. o será que accedo mediante ip por lo que no me muestra imagen previa?

Answer (score 2):

### Versión de Angular SocialShare posterior a Abril de 2017

A partir de Abril de 2017 **se eliminó el atributo socialshare-media** para indicar la imágen que aparece en el share de Facebook. Si este es tu caso deberías utilizar los [metas de OpenGraph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup) para establecer la imagen que se verá en el share. Los metas son etiquetas que se establecen a la página web en cuestión (en tu caso la del enlace del <a>)

Puedes ver el [aviso en el README](https://github.com/720kb/angular-socialshare#facebook) del proyecto en la sección de facebook.

### Versión de Angular SocialShare anterior a Abril 2017

Puede que `http://ip:3001/images/logo.png` fuera tu **ip local** para desarrollo?

Piensa que **la imagen que indiques tiene que ser accesible por facebook**, por lo que en entornos de desarrollo si indicas tu ip local o la ip interna del servidor de desarrollo Facebook no puede acceder a la imagen y por lo tanto no la mostrará cuando intentes compartir dicho contenido.

Comment: la ip es publica, de hecho no es de donde estoy desarrollando esta alojada en un servidor en otra ciudad y si pongo esa ruta, si veo la imagen en el navegador.

Comment: En ese caso tu problema seguro es que utilizas una versión de Angular SocialShare moderna en la que quitaron el parámetro socialshare-media. He editado la respuesta con dicha información.

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que se debes pasarle la ruta de la imagen completa a facebook por lo cual `http://ip:3001/images/logo.png` no es valido.
debería ser:

`<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />`

aquí te dejo el depurador de facebook para que lo veas en tiempo real:
[Depurador de contenido compartido Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/)